# Excel VBA - get cell row for a range from another cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Sub Button7_Click()
Worksheets("Contracts").Range("AI2").Value = _
InputBox(Prompt:="registrera kontrakts-id.")
End Sub
```

When using the code above, cell AI2 is updated on the "contract" sheet.

But, I need to fetch the row number from a value in cell C2 of the current sheet.

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
Worksheets("Contracts").Range("AI" & C2).Value = _
```

How can I get the "range" to use static column id (AI) but pick the row from cell C2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to do it, probably the closest one to your question is this one:

```
Sub Button7_Click()
    dim myRow as long
    myRow = ActiveSheet.Range("C2")
    ActiveSheet.Range("AI" & myRow).Value = _
    InputBox(Prompt:="registrera kontrakts-id.")
End Sub
```

Another one is `ActiveSheet.Cells(myRow, "AI").Value`.

In this scenario it is absolutely **ok** to use it, but in many others `ActiveSheet` [is something to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35864330/5448626).

In general, some "sanity" check, whether the value in `Range("C2")` is valid could be useful, as far as if it is empty, text, negative number or zero an error would occur.

```
Sub Button7_Click()

    Dim myRow As Long
    myRow = ActiveSheet.Range("C2")
    
    If Not IsNumeric(myRow) Then
        MsgBox "C2 is not numeric!"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf myRow <= 0 Then
        MsgBox "C2 is smaller or equal than 0!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("AI" & myRow).Value = InputBox(Prompt:="registrera kontrakts-id.")
    
End Sub
```